# Cookie для всплывающего окошка

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать, чтобы в данном всплывающем окне кнопка "больше не показывать" сохраняла в cookie пользователя информацию о том, что больше это окно выводить не надо при следующих посещениях сайта?

```
<!-- Модальное Окно  -->
<div id="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <p>текст</p>
    <button class="dont-show-me">больше не показывать</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var delay_popup = 1000;
  setTimeout("document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь модальное окно изначально отображается, а при нажатии на кнопку исчезает, в это же время устанавливается необходимое cookie. При обновлении страницы, окно, конечно же, не появится. Если же обновить страницу через минуту (время действия cookie), то установленное cookie удалится и модальное окно появится вновь.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Модальное Окно  -->
<div id="overlay" style="border: 1px solid black;">
  <div class="popup">
    <p>текст</p>
    <button id="hide_popup" class="dont-show-me">больше не показывать</button>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookie_arr = document.cookie.split('; ');
        let cookie_obj = {};

        for (let i=0; i<cookie_arr.length; i++) {
            let nv = cookie_arr[i].split('=');
            cookie_obj[nv[0]] = nv[1]; 
        }

        return cookie_obj[name];
    }        

    let overlay_div = document.getElementById('overlay');

    if ( getCookie('hide_popup') == 'yes' ) {
        overlay_div.style.display='none';
    }

    // При нажатии на кнопку ставим cookie, которая будет запрещать показ
    // модального окна
    document.getElementById('hide_popup')
        .addEventListener('click', function() { 
            // Ставим cookie на минуту.                
            var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 1000);
            document.cookie = "hide_popup=yes; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();

            // и сразу же скрываем окно
            overlay_div.style.display='none';
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Подробнее о работе с cookie на JavaScript можно прочитать [здесь](http://learn.javascript.ru/cookie).

Comment: Спасибо, только данный пример не работал, пока я каждый "let" не заменил на "var".